# Languages in vim editor

Tags: linux, rhel5, vim, vimrc

How to insert copy-paste a hindi language word from web pages to vim editor.When i do it now it says "..... . ....." What is the settings that has to be changed in vim editor to do this

Thanks..

Answer (score 3):

1. Make sure the locale is installed on the system (debian/ubuntu: aptitude install locale)
2. On the shell: `setenv LANG`
3. In vim:      `:language`
4. In vim:  `:set encoding=utf-8`
5. Try again and tell me if it works

I also found this while googling:
http://raviratlami1.blogspot.com/2007/04/how-to-write-hindi-in-linux.html

and thats the vim docu:
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/mbyte.html

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the points listed by *frisbee23*, you should also make sure that you're using a UTF8-capable terminal (gnome-terminal, konsole, urxvt, etc), and that the terminal font you've selected supports displaying Hindi characters.